# Static resource in managed package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, beta-managed-package

I am using 5 static resources in my org to display a map.

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/compatibleBootsrap, /resource/BootstrapSF1" 
   scripts=" /resource/jQuery, /resource/raphael, /resource/usmap" 
   afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.performInit}"/>
```

While creating a managed package I am unable to get the output might be due to namespace used in my org. What can be the proper workaround for this?

Please help as I am new in lightning.

Comment: Have you tried using $Resource global variable instead of hard coding the value?

Comment: If I am using $Resource global variable it is not giving me the expected output and my functionality is properly working without any namespace but if I create a managed package for my component and the static resources,the output doesn't come.

Comment: Also, is compatibleBootsrap correct? Seems there's a missing letter.

Comment: Have you opened up the console on the client to see what is getting requested? If the client is not loading them, there should be plenty of errors in the browser console to help you chase this down.

Comment: It also depends on which context you're in. These urls won't work in site.com pages. The only way to load them if your doing a site.com community is to upload them to the site.com resources and figure out what the url will be or hardcode the salesfoce domain to load them from static resources.

Answer (score 5):

Try this it will work for sure.
First keep the scripts and style in a separate tag.
Second for namespace use like this;

for stylesheet we can use

```
<link href="/resource/namespace__resourceName" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ltng:require script="/resource/namespace__resourceName....."/>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation about [Using External JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm) it is noted that in a managed package context, you will still reference the path to the resource with `/resource/resourceName` but you will need to prefix the resource name with your managed package namespace: `/resource/pkg__resourceName`.

> Note that the framework doesn’t currently support the `$Resource` global variable available in Visualforce. In a managed packaged, the resource name must include the package namespace prefix, such as `/resource/np_resourceName`.

The documentation only shows a single underscore prefixing the name but I suspect that it is probably two underscores there.

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/yourNS__compatibleBootstrap, /resource/yourNS__BootstrapSF1" 
   scripts="/resource/yourNS__jQuery, /resource/yourNS__raphael, /resource/yourNS__usmap" 
   afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.performInit}"/>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I just need to added my namespace.

Answer (score 0):

(This is similar to another question I answered but with namespaces)

What I found was that if you have selected a bunch of files and zipped then up (ie no containing folder), then for a bunch of resources eg these three folders:

```
css
    bootstrap.css
    lookahead.css
js
    jquery-1.1.0.js
    bootstrap.js
    lookahead.js
```

for a namespace 'ns' you would use a path of `/resource/ns_resource_name_defined_on_upload/js/boostrap.js` to access the boostrap file.

However, if you zipped up a containing folder and you had a structure like this:

```
my_assets
    css
        bootstrap.css
        lookahead.css
    js
        jquery-1.1.0.js
        bootstrap.js
        lookahead.js
```

for a namespace 'ns' you would use a path of `/resource/ns_resource_name_defined_on_upload/my_assets/js/boostrap.js` to access the boostrap file.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.nameOfStaticResource,
 'folderItLivesIn/bootstrap.min.js')}"></apex:includeScript>
```

You can use the same format for all static resources and you never have to hard code anything.... nor should you :)

edit... As James below noted the question is regarding lightning components and my above solution is for VF pages. I believe the problem might be in that you are not refering to the file extension at the end of the name. See this:

> Notes:
>
> Files paths must always start from /resource. i.e they must be a
>   static resource to enforce security.
>
> CDNs are not allowed at this point because they are outside of
>   Salesforce data centers and can’t be controlled. In the future, we may
>   allow admins to whitelist CDNs for their orgs.
>
> If you upload a JS or CSS directly into Static resource, then you
>   should reference them by resource name without .css or .js suffix. For
>   example:  /resource/myjsfile or /resource/mycssfile
>
> If your resource is inside a zip file, then you should use .css or .js
>   suffix. For example: /resource//path/to/myjsfile.js

from here: [SF developer docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/05/loading-external-js-css-libraries-lightning-components.html)

Comment: Not only is the includeScript for Visualforce, but the URLFOR method and $Resource global variable don't currently work in Lightning either, and the OP is looking specifically for lightning component help.

Comment: James, what would you propose besides down voting?